# React hooks + Firebase state value after POST request does not display until hard refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

So after every POST request, only composerName and message field are correctly displayed (don't want sorter node to be displayed) and the timestamp is not. When I console.log the data, everything is there. No error or warnings. I can also see everything in their place after a hard refresh of the page.

Also, when I type something into input text area, onChange seems to trigger re-render of the component after each keystroke, and then I can see the timestamp being displayed and even updated. Maybe I'm using useEffect hooks in a wrong way? I assume this is the issue but I can't move any further from here.

Chatroom.js before return jsx:

```
// import statements

const Chatroom = ({ match }) => {
  // ...
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {

    let messagesRef = db
      .ref(`REFERENCE`)
      .orderByChild('sorter')
      .limitToFirst(numOfMessagesPerLoad)

    setMessagesLoading(true)

    messagesRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      const messagesList = []

      snapshot.forEach(data => {
        messagesList.push(data.val())
      })

      setMessages(messagesList)
      setMessagesLoading(false)
    })

    return () => messagesRef.off()
  }, [])

  // ...

  const postMessageHandler = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setPosting(true)

    try {
      const newMessage = {
        composerName:
          'Name ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100).toString(), // just to make each composerName unique
        creationTime: Date.now(),
        sorter: Date.now() * -1,
        message,
      }
      const res = await axios.post(`ENDPOINT`, newMessage)

      setMessages([res.data.data.message, ...messages])
      setMessage('')
      setPosting(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message)
    }
  }
```

Chatroom.js return jsx:

```
  return (
    <>
      <section className="main-comments">
        <div className="main-comments-top">
          // ...

          <div className="comment-form">
            <Form className="comment-send-form" onSubmit={postMessageHandler}>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="text"
                value={message}
                placeholder="Say something..."
                className="comment-form-input"
                onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              />

              <Button
                className="msg-send-button"
                type="submit"
                disabled={message.length === 0}
              >
                {posting ? (
                  <ClipLoader size={20} color="#8585ff" />
                ) : (
                  <span>Post</span>
                )}
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>

          // ...

        <div id="comments" className="comments">
          <div className="comments-area">
            {messages.length === 0 && !messagesLoading ? (
              <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <p>This feed has no messages yet.</p>
              </div>
            ) : (
              messages
                .sort((a, b) => {
                  return a.sorter - b.sorter
                })
                .map(msg => (
                  <div className="com-each-comment" key={msg.creationTime}>
                    <div className="user-and-comment">
                      <p className="username-display">
                        <span>{msg.composerName}</span>
                      </p>
                      <p className="com-text-comment">{msg.message}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="comment-footer">
                      <small className="comment-timestamp">
                        {timeSince(msg.creationTime)} // this is not being displayed until hard refresh
                        // timeSince() is just a custom function that I wrote to change timestamp format
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Chatroom
```

Thank you

More Info: When tested through postman, things work and get displayed just as expected

Comment: Update: it is working as expected. But the funny thing is, I didn't change anything